# Why my scroll to much slow in internet explorer

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, scrollview, scrollbar

I have been working on a web site for quite some time. The work of the web site is almost over. Now when I was testing my site in all browsers, I saw a problem with my website. The scroll of my website is very good chorome, firefox, brave. But internet explorer scroll is very slow. Which is why every time I scroll through the internet explorer, the sections of my website are split one by one.

Comment: quick fix - use a modern browser - or show some code that demonstrates the issue - nobody can help with code that is non-existant

Comment: What is your OS version and IE version? Besides, please provide [a minimal code snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which can **reproduce the issue** so that we can have a test and see how to help. With only the text description, we can't locate the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Add scroll-behavior: smooth to the  element to enable smooth scrolling for the whole page (note: it is also possible to add it to a specific element/scroll container):

```
    <style>
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
</style>
```

Comment: I had used it. But this property is not working on the internet explorer

Comment: Share your site URL

Comment: The site is a local server. I have been not uploading my website to the live server.
it's a locally scroll problem. I think this problem will here in live server